# How to stop Gravatar setting cookies

Tags: php, html, cookies, gravatar

I am using the Gravatar service on my website. However there is a problem: it sets two cookies, `gravatar` and `__qca`, which cause users with 3rd party cookies blocked to see a warning that the site tried to set 3rd party cookies. I don't want this to happen.

The cookies themselves are obviously useless - Gravatar works fine if I block them. They are likely for tracking purposes, which is another reason to block them.

My questions to Gravatar have not been answered.

So how can I stop Gravatar setting cookies?

Comment: don't use gravatar? it's a free service - they need to make money somehow, and tracking cookies are a cash cow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my second email I got this response:

> Hey,
>
> Thanks for contacting us. We're currently looking into the reason why
>   these cookies are set and checking to see if we can remove them
>   without any repercussions. I'll let you know as soon as we've got an
>   answer for you!
>
> Best,
>
> Phil WordPress.com | Automattic Inc.

I'll update this if they contact me again.

---

**EDIT:** I haven't got another email from them, but it looks like those cookies no longer are set in Gravatar image requests. Thanks Gravatar!

Comment: They are back setting cookies again.. So I'm going to avoid using gravatar in my projects from now on..

Comment: Chrome is now (Version 78.0.3904.97) showing a warning:

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://gravatar.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: Response from Gravatar support: Thanks for getting in touch! We're aware of this issue and are working to resolve that by the time the future release of Chrome lands.

Answer (score 0):

GDPR wants me to communicate every possible privacy risk (that includes cookies).

My conclusion: I am not going to use avatar any more.